# Copying shadows from Illustrator to Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, shadows, white

Whenever I copy something from Illustrator and paste it into Photoshop as a smart object, the shadows always become weird looking and I don't know how to fix that.

Illustrator (original project):

[image]

Photoshop:

[image]

I've been researching this for a while but haven't found a solution because I mostly don't understand some of the terms and tricks that are posted. I have zero experience with Illustrator, but I can work with Photoshop a bit and that's why I want to move those AI projects (that I buy ready-made) to Photoshop so I can work with it.

Everything has been working out flawlessly for me doing it this way, except when I come across shadows!

Comment: You can not have multiple different blending modes in one object

Comment: What format are the files you bought?  EPS? AI?

Answer (score 1):

## Change how the shadows are structured.

Use *transparency* rather than blending modes.

[image]

[image]

Note that when using transparency you **want** *both* color stops to be the same color. This will help control the drop off within the gradient.

This does *slightly* alter appearance on a background since there's no blending mode at play. If the blending is imperative, import your shadows to Photoshop as *separate* objects. You can then reassign a blending mode there.

---

Disclosure.... I am a bit "old school" and do my level best to *avoid* ever using *any* blending mode within Illustrator. Or I *flatten* the artwork/objects after using a blending mode option.

---

You can also merely remove the shadows in Illustrator and recreate them in Photoshop.